# xcodebuild command line: passing DevelopmentTeam ID for code signing purpose

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcodebuild

My App is given one bundleID for App Store distribution. The App also has a small variant for enterprise distribution, thus with another bundleID. The automatic build uses the following command line to set bundleID and pick the right signing identify:

```
xcodebuild -project XYZ.xcodeproj -target XYZ -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration "Debug" BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=<bundleID_1_or_2> CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="<identify_1_or_2" build
```

This automatic build has been working great, until recently I enabled iCloud capability. Now Xcode automatically adds the following to project.pbxproj:

```
TargetAttributes = {
  QWERTY1234567890123456 = {
  DevelopmentTeam = XYZ123456;
    SystemCapabilities = {
      com.apple.iCloud = {
        enabled = 1;
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Notice the addition of a hard-coded "DevelopmentTeam = XYZ123456"; for the two builds, the DevelopmentTeam ID is different. How to automate this? An easier solution is to have a script to modify project.pbxproj before invoking xcodebuild, but I am not a fan of that solution. The next best is to create a new "User Defined Setting" thus passing it via command line, but I could not figure out how to associate the User-Defined Setting with that DevelopmentTeam ID embedded there inside project.pbxproj.

Comment: I have a similar problem. And for now I modify pbxproj file by text replacing (the easiest solution from your question). I spent much time to find another solution but with no luck. Can you clarify - what is QWERTY1234567890123456? Looks like this guid should be replaced too for different Apple developer accounts.

Comment: That string is the internal ID for a target; in this case, it is the target for the main App. No you do not need to replace it because you want the main App to be enabled with iCloud capability. PS, I had to resort to a python script to do the replacement of the DevelopmentTeam ID.

Answer (score 9):

In **Xcode 8** this was added as `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` build setting.
You can pass as a command line argument just like other settings:

```
xcodebuild
    -sdk "iphoneos"
    -project Foo.xcodeproj
    -configuration "Debug"
...
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=XYZ123456
```

See in more detail about Xcode 8 code signing changes: [https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20190308022003/https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html)

Comment: Why its so difficult? Why why why why... why its not well documented? can you please show how to use no the xcodeproj file but use `xcworkspace` ?

Answer (score 5):

We were able to deal with multiple DevelopmentTeam IDs by using the [sigh](https://github.com/KrauseFx/sigh) utility, which provides automation for provisioning profiles.  We use it as part of the [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) suite of tools.

```
sigh --team_id <DevelopmentTeamID>
```

Or as part of a fastlane automation ([Fastfile](https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane/blob/master/docs/Actions.md#developer-portal)):

```
sigh(team_id: "<DevelopmentTeamID>")
```

Comment: How can I find DevelopmentTeamID ?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up creating another debug-like build configuration.  In our case it's called "Ad-hoc" for no particular reason.  Our build server uses an enterprise certificate for test builds so we just changed that build configuration to have the correct certificate and team parameters, and the development "Debug" ones are no longer important.  One thing that is challenging though is that some cocoapods (fbtweaks) don't realise you may be using a configuration that isn't called "Debug" to create debug builds, so there are some hoops that have to be jumped through to make that work correctly.

Comment: can you explain more about how you set the team on a per-configuration basis? it only appears on the General. not the build settings where per-configuration items can be set.